# CanvasJS react redraws entire chart on data refresh

Tags: reactjs, canvasjs

Whenever I update the datasets of my CanvasJS component, all lines get re-drawn (in an animated fashion) instead of the points simply being added to the end. How can I prevent this?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpBcJ.jpg (short clip of the re-drawing, can't inline this it seems.)

I'm currently calling setState every 5 seconds through an interval (which polls an API). In the top of my render method I perform some transformations to the array saved in state (e.g. `.map((e) => { return { x: e.x, y: e.y }; });`), and then I pass the resulting array to data of the CanvasJSChart.

Edit:
I have just found the following page: https://canvasjs.com/react-charts/dynamic-live-line-chart/. This however sounds like a terrible anti-pattern. I'm going to see about wrapping this in a component which returns false on shouldComponentUpdate, but I'm not sure if that will work. If anyone has a better idea, please let me know.

Comment: Can you share sample in either JSFiddle or [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/canvasjs-react-basic-column-chart) - which makes others understand your scenario & guide you accordingly?